# Why does a sum operation in php throws an incorrect result?

Tags: php

I have a very specific case, when i do this sum in any calculator it throws the correct result:

```
2.0 + 1.7 + 0.85 + 0.35 = 4,9
```

But i try the same operation in php and get a  strange result:

```
2.0 + 1.7 + 0.85 + 0.35 = 4.8999999999999995
```

The weird part is that if i remove the last number i get a "correct" result:

```
2.0 + 1.7 + 0.85 = 4,55
```

Can anybody help me get the correct result in every case